# Syntax issues when using string variables in DLOOKUP function in VBA for Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to teach myself VBA for Access and am having some issues with the syntax for using text variables in a DLOOKUP function.

I am attempting to loop through a recordset one record at a time to see if two separate text fields from my recordset exist in the same two fields in a separate access table.  If they do exist in the table, then I want to create an error message and display a message stating record exists already

```
Dim str1 As String
Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("temptbl")

Do Until rst.EOF
If Not IsNull(DLookup("Entry_Number" and "HTS_Line", "PO_Payment", 
("Entry_Number= '" & rst!Entry_Number & "'") and ("HTS_Line= '" & 
rst!HTS_Line & "'"))) Then
    str1 = MsgBox("Entry number "" & rst!Entry_Number & "" already exists in 
    the PO_Payment table.  Please investigate.", vbOKOnly)
    Exit Do
    rst.Close
    DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, "temptbl"
```

All fields are data type text but I am receiving a code 13 type mismatch error and cannot understand why.  Can anyone help please?

Comment: Are both `Entry_Number` and `HTS_Line` text columns? `Entry_Number` sounds an awful lot like a number.

Comment: Yes, both columns are text columns.  The entry number is a field that contains special characters.

Answer (score 0):

```vb
DLookup("Entry_Number" and "HTS_Line", "PO_Payment", ...
```

The first parameter is invalid. It must be a single string, containing a column name or an expression.

E.g.

```vb
DLookup("Entry_Number", "PO_Payment", ...
```

or

```vb
DLookup("[Entry_Number] & ', ' & [HTS_Line]", "PO_Payment", ...
```

Comment: Thanks Andre, I appreciate your help!!

Comment: For some reason I am still getting the type mismatch error.  I think my syntax in the criteria may be wrong, but cannot seem to get it right.